# What's a safe way to sign into your react native app using another existing web app/server?

Tags: react-native

As the title suggests, I'm starting to work on a React Native project that will be an extension (or side app) of another company's already-existing web application. They already have thousands of users in their DB and their own server of course. We have just started conversations with them about opening up their APIs for us to extend our additions to their product on the app. However, their team is also small and it seems like they don't have experience with sharing credentials across apps without fully opening up the API (there's a security concern, I suppose mainly around attacks).

I have seen some patterns used on some apps where it seems like React Native opens up the web app's login page on a webview and via a callback stores credentials. However, I'm not sure if that's a) really possible, b) secure, c) the most efficient way.

More infra and technicalities are still up in the air. I am mainly looking for guidance or resources as I work on this investigation. I am happy to clarify as much as I can if anything is not clear.